# Why does rm -f ask me for confirmation on zsh?

Tags: zsh

I'm running zsh from Cygwin. One of my shell functions contains a statement

```
rm -f somedir/*
```

(I want to remove all non-hidden files in somedir, but not the directory itself). However, I am always asked:

```
zsh: sure you want to delete all the files in ... [yn]?
```

The wording of this message (note the "zsh:" at the beginning) suggests that the question comes from zsh, not rm. However, rm is an external command:

```
$ type rm
rm is /usr/bin/rm
```

By the way, the prompt also occurs if I explicitly invoke rm as

```
$ command rm -f somedir/*
```

Is there something within zsh, which tries to be too clever?

Comment: is this alias present in your .zshrc: alias rm='rm -i' ?

Comment: Just type alias to check

Comment: No, as you see from my posting, I used both 'type' and 'command'. 'type' would have revealed, if their would be an alias, and 'command' would bypass it. Also note that the confirmation question doesn't come from rm, but from zsh, as we can conclude from the wording.

Comment: AND it does NOT DELETE my files. Wait press `y`.

Comment: Please see my amended answer, which demonstrates my solution at work using sudo in a ZSH shell.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

It seems that the `RM_STAR_SILENT` is **NOT** in effect.
You could do `setopt rmstarsilent` either in the command line or in ~/.zshrc to tell zsh to not confirm a `rm *`.

The shell option `RM_STAR_SILENT` is:

> Do not query the user before executing `rm *` or `rm path/*`.
>
> -- [`zshoptions(1): RM_STAR_SILENT`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-RMSTARSILENT)

---

If you want to make the `setopt` effect temporally just in that shell function only, you could use it in conjunction with the [`localoptions`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-LOCALOPTIONS) like below:

```shell
my-test () {
  setopt localoptions rmstarsilent
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the bit about `localoptions`! That is exactly what I needed. I like this feature, except in specific functions where I'm clearing log files, I don't want to be prompted then!

Comment: Ii is still unclear to me, how to call rm command without prompt. BTW in which language the code above is written?

Comment: How to make this change permanent? I need to do this every time I start a new shell.

Comment: To use locally, just run `setopt localoptions rmstarsilent` in the terminal. To make permanent, add that line to `~/.zshrc` and reload the terminal. The example in the answer is showing using it in a shell function.

Comment: It is absolutely unclear to me how this is not a bug of zsh, when `-f` is explicitly wanted. The doc on `rm` `-f` says: **never prompt**. zsh should not overwrite this in my opinion. At least it does not promt when called from a script.

Comment: Instead of `setopt localoptions rmstarsilent` can we do: `setopt rmstarsilent`?

Answer (score -12):

You need to recursively set permissions on all files and folders within the directory `somedir` to `rw`, and then execute:

```
sudo rm -rf somedir
```

[Here's a video](https://app.box.com/s/ldtoel8mw7dp1r8mqke6yuo2s1k1lmhe) of my successful use of sudo for this command in a ZSH shell.

Comment: 1. `sudo` has nothing to do with the `rm` confirmation  
2. if you're running a command with `sudo`, you don't need to set permissions as the superuser can delete anything anyways

Comment: @FeldsLiscia - Have you tried both your way and mine? If not, you might be as surprised as I was that “super doing” is not always the same as “super being” (at least not in this case)…

Comment: The reason `sudo` behaves differently than just being root is that `sudo` doesn't execute commands in a shell. Running `rm ./*` in `zsh` will generate the warning even if you're root, but using `sudo` means no shell is started under the superuser, so there's no `zsh` between your input and the system to generate the warning. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37817783

Comment: @eritbh See my amended answer, which now links to a video showing my solution at work.

Comment: I never said your method didn't work, it's just a bad answer because you're becoming root for something that doesn't require you to be root. Your method works, not because of the elevated permissions, but because `sudo` doesn't run its input under a shell. There are other mechanisms for executing programs without a shell that don't require root; for example, `sudo -u $USER` will have the same effect as `sudo` here (though it still doesn't seem like a better option than the accepted answer).

Comment: @eritbh So, you watched the video I posted, then? At what specific point did I make an error or a necessary maneuver?