# What shell does sudo use

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sudo

My apologies as this has to be a question others have asked but it seems google proof. I'm trying to figure out what shell is being invoked as I have met an inconsistency. My script doesn't work if I `sudo`, but does work if I `sudo bash`. Yet when I `sudo echo $0`, it says bash.

```
cpu=$(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep Revision | cut -d' ' -f 2-);
if [[ "a22082" = $cpu || "a02082" = $cpu ]]; then
    echo 'do stuff';
fi
```

If I specify the command interpreter with *#!/bin/sh* it still fails but being more specific *#!/bin/bash* it does.

I *(now)* know that `[[` is bash specific but despite the response it doesn't seem like sudo's default shell is bash.

Comment: `sudo echo $(SHELL)` ? Perhaps that might help

Comment: Wait, I'm assuming that `sh` and `bash` aren't the same shell. Why would you expect it to work when you're specifying the wrong shell?

Comment: I always found it personally to me to put `#!/bin/sh` for the shebang and found it better practice to put the exact shell to use.

Comment: @Hasturkun `sh` says use the default system shell, `bash` says to use the bash shell

Comment: @EdHeal, I just tried to do this on Mac OS (the question's about Linux, but still), and bash seems to execute `$(SHELL)` _before `sudo`_ as I first got `-bash: SHELL: command not found` and only then - a prompt to input a password. So I guess that bash is running `$(SHELL)` without `sudo`.

Comment: @jgr208: `sh` is a Bourne Shell (compatible) shell, `bash` is the Bourne Again Shell, which has it's own features. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5725402 . My point is that if you're using `bash` features, use `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Perhaps I should have put some quotes in

Comment: Perhaps `sudo env` or `sudo set`

Comment: just put shebang like `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash` at the beginning of your script and everything will work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Short answer:** There is no default interpreter. Your script needs a shebang line `#!/bin/bash` at the top.

**Long answer:** `sudo` does not run a shell. It runs the command you pass it directly, no intermediate shell. If you want a shell you need to explicitly pass it one.

> ```
> sudo echo $0
> ```

This command is misleading due to `$0` being expanded by your shell *before `sudo` is called*. It's printing your current `$0`, not the value of `$0` inside the `sudo`'d environment.

Let's compare some commands:

- ```
  sudo ls
  ```

  This executes the `/bin/ls` executable directly. There's no shell involved. The following commands will show when the distinction comes into play.
- ```
  sudo ls /root/*
  ```

  The current shell expands the glob. If you can't access `/root/` then the glob isn't expanded and you get `ls: cannot access /root/*: No such file or directory`.
- ```
  sudo 'ls /root/*'
  ```

  This attempts to execute a program called `ls /root/*`. Literally, it's named `*` in the `root` sub-directory of `ls`  (`ls` with a trailing space). It fails with `sudo: ls /root/*: command not found`.
- ```
  sudo ls '/root/*'
  ```

  This runs `/bin/ls` and passes it the literal string `/root/*`. There's no glob expansion. It fails with `ls: cannot access /root/*: No such file or directory`.
- ```
  sudo bash -c 'ls /root/*'
  ```

  This executes `/bin/bash` and has it interpolate the `ls /root/*` command-line, expanding the glob. This one, finally, works, because we have an explicit shell to expand the glob, and we're doing the expansion within `sudo` instead of outside of it.

Comment: in  `sudo a=e printenv`, who parse `a=e` to enviroment then?

Comment: @JiangYD `sudo` processes variable assignments preceding the command.

Comment: do you mean that the sudo program parse `a=e` string then invoke the `printenv` program with the parsed enviroments?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 6):

To complement [John Kugelman's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37817783/45375) by addressing the more general question implied by the post's title:

<sup>On a side note: It's best to always start your scripts with a shebang line to explicitly control what shell it is run by.</sup>

`sudo` doesn't run a shell *by default*, but can be made to run one with either of the following options:

- `-s` (non-login shell)

  - uses the shell specified via the `$SHELL` environment variable, if defined, otherwise the shell defined in the user's password database entry (`/etc/passwords`)
- `-i` (login shell, always uses the shell from the user's )

  - uses  the shell defined in the user's password database entry

In other words: **`sudo` uses the *current* user's default shell, unless, for `-s` only, overridden via `$SHELL`**.

See `man sudo` for details.